# SSRS - Sub report within a sub report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I am building a report that the user can export and I am running in to some difficulties. I would love some input from somebody as I am starting to grey a little.

---

### The Issue

I have `CalcTable` that stores parent rows for `CalcTableMonthly`. To retrieve rows from `CalcTable` I use identifier `LeaseID`. Then due to there being multiple rows in `CalcTable` under one `LeaseID` and each one row in `CalcTable` will have multiple monthly values in `CalcTableMonthly`.

The `MainReport` gets the values from `CalcTable` via the `LeaseID`.

The `SubReport1` gets values from the `CalcTableMonthly` via again the `LeaseID`. These values are a combination of all available `CalcTable` rows that have values in `CalcTableMonthly`.

Then Finally `SubReport2` gets all of the combined values for that month. So I must pass in the `LeaseID` and `Month` from SubReport1.

So you can see that it works as far as level 2.

[image]

### Page Load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Get LeaseID from query string
            sqls_Summary.SelectParameters["LeaseID"].DefaultValue = Request["LeaseID"];
            // Set report path
            this.rep_Main.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\\CalculationReports\\rpt_Summary_Export.rdlc";
            // Set Report DataSources
            this.rep_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsLeaseCalculations", sqls_Summary));
            this.rep_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsLeaseCalculationsMonths", sqls_Summary_Months));
            this.rep_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsLeaseCalculationsViewMonth", sqls_Summary_ViewMonth));
            // Set the subreport processing event.
            this.rep_Main.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(subReportProccessingFunc);
            this.rep_Main.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }

    }
```

### Subreport Processing Event

```
public void subReportProccessingFunc(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        sqls_Summary_Months.SelectParameters["LeaseID"].DefaultValue = e.Parameters["prmLeaseID"].Values.First();
        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsLeaseCalculationsMonths", sqls_Summary_Months));

        sqls_Summary_ViewMonth.SelectParameters["LeaseID"].DefaultValue = e.Parameters["prmLeaseID"].Values.First();
        sqls_Summary_ViewMonth.SelectParameters["Month"].DefaultValue = // What to put here????
        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsLeaseCalculationsViewMonth", sqls_Summary_ViewMonth));
    }
```

From the above code the line `sqls_Summary_ViewMonth.SelectParameters["Month"].DefaultValue =` I am unsure how to handle. How can I retrieve the month from the current row in the RDLC report?

### Things I have tried

1. Googling for similar issues, was unable to find anything
2. Setting the DefaultValue to `e.Parameters["LiabilityDate"].Values.First()`, did not work as it was not picking up the value.

That is about it since I really have no idea...

---

### **Summary**

I have 1 main report, that main report has a subreport which has another subreport. To retrieve the subreport I pass the LeaseID value only to it. The first subreport also only requires LeaseID **BUT** second subreport that is located withing first subreport requies the LeaseID **AND** the month. I am unsure how I can get this month variable in the subreport in RDLC as it **works in rdl in report builder as seen by the image below** but sadly does not work when I use it in ASP.net

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some tinkering and walking away from my desk I had a think and I thought of a solution.

I created another SubreportProcessingEventHandler within the first function.

```
public void subReportProccessingFunc(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
   sqls_Summary_Months.SelectParameters["LeaseID"].DefaultValue = 
   e.Parameters["prmLeaseID"].Values.First();
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsLeaseCalculationsMonths", 
   sqls_Summary_Months));

   this.rep_Main.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(subReportProccessingFunc1);
}

public void subReportProccessingFunc1(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
   sqls_Summary_ViewMonth.SelectParameters["LeaseID"].DefaultValue = e.Parameters["prmLeaseID"].Values.First();
   sqls_Summary_ViewMonth.SelectParameters["Month"].DefaultValue = e.Parameters["prmMonth"].Values.First();
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsLeaseCalculationsViewMonth", sqls_Summary_ViewMonth));
}
```

So once the first subreport is processed the second one acts like a main report again and another sub report is processed in its place. I was able to select the prmMonth value for that row and it all worked!

Hope it helps anyone that stumbles upon this!